# onPasswordFailed alternative

Tags: android, screen-lock

I implemented listener `onPasswordFailed`, but it gets called only when lock screen PIN is wrong and longer than the actual PIN. Are there any alternative listeners that get called even if entered pin is shorter?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: `@Override
    public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("mydevice", "wrong ping");
        super.onPasswordFailed(context, intent);
    }`

Comment: I mean the whole code snippet. How did you implement your alternative of `onPasswordFailed`?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, I am actually looking for an alternative. I would have to change android implementation in order to change current behavior, am I right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "change the Android implementation."

Comment: I cannot change the behavior of android's event, that is why I am looking for an alternate event.